# connection.playStream is not a function

Tags: javascript, discord.js

I know that there are a lot of question on this topic, but I browsed all of them but none of the answers seemed to fix my issue. I'm just creating a Discord bot for fun, I have almost never programmed in JavaScript but I wanted to try it.

My Code looks like this:

```
    var url = "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=HHv-s2OqYpw"

    if(!message.member.voice.channel){
        message.channel.send("Join a voice channel.");
        return
    } else {
        vc = message.member.voice.channel;
        connection = await vc.join();
        isValid = ytdl.validateURL(url);
        if(!isValid){
            message.channel.send("The url you gave doesn't exist");
        } else {
            const stream = ytdl(url, {filter: "audioonly"});
            const dispatcher = connection.playStream(stream)

            dispatcher.on("end", function() {
                vc.leave()
                message.channel.send("Done playing the only music I can play lol")
            })
```

I could do that it could play more songs but I only want it to play this one and in the terminal i get this error:

```
connection.playStream is not a function
```

I do have ytdl-core and opusscript installed and they both have the newest version. I tried doing this in lots of different ways, and it really annoys me that I can't figure out what the problem is. Sorry for bad english and thank those who help me. Have a nice day!

Answer (score 1):

https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/VoiceConnection?scrollTo=play

As you can see, there's a `VoiceConnection#play()` method, and since you're most likely on v12, this is the method you're looking for.

```js
const stream = ytdl(url, options);
const dispatcher = connection.play(stream);
```